# Kineticjs: How to delete a Group and all its Children?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

How can I delete a group and all its children?

I found this post [How to let a user delete a group of objects in kineticjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587498/how-to-let-a-user-delete-a-group-of-objects-in-kineticjs) which does not really answers the question.

I would do it like this:

```
group.destroyChildren();
group.destroy();
```

**Is this the correct way or can I also use only the last line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group.destroy() alone because group.destroy() also destroys all its children.